# Posteriod distribution of Normal Inverse Gamma model

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem, gamma-distribution

I want to derive the posterior distribution (without the normalizing constant) of:
$$p(\mu,\sigma^2)=p(\mu| \sigma^2)p(\sigma^2)$$
with $$\mu|\sigma^2 \sim N(2,1.7^2\sigma^2) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \sigma^2\sim IG(10,20)$$
IG denotes an inverse-gamma distribution. I know the solution is an Inverse gamma distribution but I need to find out the rate and scale parameters. Does anyone know how to derive the posterior?

Comment: An inverse gamma distribution density is a function of one variable, while $p(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a function of two variables here proportional to something like $y^{-11} \exp\left(-\tfrac{(x-2)^2}{2\times 1.7^2 y}-\tfrac{20}{y}\right)$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution

Comment: I'm only interested in the posterior of sigma^2(since mu is fixed). I get something in the line of $$p(\mu| \sigma^2)p(\sigma^2) \propto \sigma^{2^{-a-1}}exp(\frac{-b}{\sigma^2})\times 1.7^{-2n}\sigma^{2^{-n/2}}exp(-\frac{\sum(x_i-2)^2}{2\times1.7^2\times\sigma^2})\propto \sigma^{2^{-(a+n/2)-1}}exp(-\frac{b+\sum(x_i-2)^2/(2\times 1.7^2)}{\sigma^2})\sim IG(a+n/2,b+\sum(x_i-2)^2/2*1.7^2),$$ 
with $a=10$ and $b=20$.@Henry

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle the 1.7^2, feels like I'm doing something wrong @Henry